# Trying to install nodemon in termimal and lost connection to npm

Tags: npm, nodemon

Just trying to learn node and I began by trying to install nodemon in terminal on my mac.
`nodemon --save-dev` and got errors to the effect that my node version was old so I ran `brew upgrade node` and got `Warning: node 13.11.0 already installed` When I checked `node -v`, I got `v6.11.3`
Confused and reading answers on the web, I messed around with the prefix for npm `npm config set prefix /usr/local/lib/node_modules` and then `npm config set prefix /usr/local` and `npm update -g` and now I can't access npm. I see the node modules are in usr/local/lib but when enter `npm root -g` get `bash: npm: command not found`...

Comment: Have you tried `brew reinstall node` ?

Comment: Thank you, it worked and I was able to install nodemon!